# Azure Logic App / Custom Connector, Validation : Import OpenAPI error "Unable to resolve schema"

Tags: azure-logic-apps

When i try to create an Azure Logic App / Custom Connector, into the last validation phase, my OpenAPI import is marked as invalid with some errors "Unable to resolve schema".

All actions and references are listed (0 trigger) but some of them have this error and avoid to validate update of connector ... The OpenAPI file (v2 json) is validate into Swagger.io and ApiMatic.io without any error ...

Someone has already resolved this issue ?

Best,

Emmanuel.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJ9z0.png)

Comment: are you trying to connect to on-premise using custom connector?

Answer (score 0):

In custom connector it might happen that some schemas are not supported or the format of the file is creating an issue. It needs dedicated troubleshooting to check where the issue lies and if this is a workable file for the custom connector. Hence I would recommend you to open a support ticket with Microsoft Support. (Please refer to : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/377280/unable-to-resolve-schema.html?childToView=380982#answer-380982)

Comment: Thanks Jaya for your answer.

I don't have / could not open a ticket with Microsoft Support.

I encounter this error when trying your solution.

WSDL import (in beta) don't work.
OPENAPI import is limited to version 2.0 (not 3.0) and json (not yaml, then in editor mode, it's yaml ??)

Below, answer form a APIMATIC.IO support:

>>> 
(...) I created a documentation portal using your swagger file and the 500 response resolves without any issues, which means that the swagger file is correct. The problem is with the custom connector which is unable to process the inherited models. (...)